# Is there (or why there is not) a matrix square root operation for sparse matrices in SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I was searching for a matrix square root operation like `scipy.linalg.sqrtm` (*not* element wise square root) on SciPy sparse matrices, but I cannot find anything. In other words, `scipy.sparse.linalg.sqrtm` does not exists. Does anybody know a way to do this operation on sparse matrices (besides converting to dense matrices and using SciPy's `linalg.sqrtm`)

People have suggested ways to do matrix powers on sparse matrices by doing `sparse_matrix**power`, but it can only handle integer powers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find `sqrtm` in `numpy`.  I do find it in the `scipy.linalg` package, `scipy.linalg.sqrtm`.

I made a random sparse matrix

```
In [377]: M=sparse.random(10,10,.2,'csr')
```

I tried the sqrtm on its dense version:

```
In [378]: linalg.sqrtm(M.A)
Matrix is singular and may not have a square root.
```

First time I tried this I got a lot of `nan`.  The second I got an array like:

```
Out[378]: 
array([[ 0.88617894 -5.55111512e-17j,  0.01749504 -2.77555756e-17j,
        -0.04458481 +2.77555756e-17j,  0.64717137 -8.32667268e-17j,
         ...
        -0.36856923 -2.77555756e-17j,  0.44353864 +3.29597460e-17j]])
```

I get this sort of result even when I apply it to `M**2`; `linalg.sqrtm((M**2).A)`.

So I think you need to dig into linear algebra theory and find if and when `sqrtm` makes sense when working with a sparse matrix.  `sqrtm` references a `Blocked Schur Algorithms` (MATLAB uses the same 2013 reference).  Do you understand that method?

---

With a larger matrix, I get a case that isn't singular:

```
In [427]: M=sparse.random(100,100,.1,'csr')
In [428]: M
Out[428]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [429]: a1=linalg.sqrtm(M.A)
In [430]: np.allclose(a1.dot(a1),M.A)
Out[430]: True
```

The resulting array does not look very sparse.  Is that an artifact of going through the dense code, or is that normal?  If the result is nearly always dense, there's little point to implementing a sparse version, is there?

```
In [431]: a1
Out[431]: 
array([[ 0.62268422+0.03131536j, -0.27157347-0.17225629j,
        -0.08630637-0.07467316j, ...,  0.09462768+0.03892438j,
         0.01204048-0.07234779j, -0.08013413+0.0382219j ],
       [-0.08049302-0.09802712j,  0.54396429+0.03354472j,
        -0.07932389+0.16519734j, ...,  0.01665645+0.03595561j,
        -0.04592068+0.03031138j,  0.19135217-0.06070762j],
       [ 0.05835017-0.05424398j,  0.05459725+0.12541806j,
         0.69837931+0.22229791j, ..., -0.07561791-0.01402142j,
         0.02495625-0.00127714j,  0.07991591-0.03378647j],
       ..., 
       [ 0.06234687-0.07739042j,  0.14074254+0.08867074j,
        -0.12518048+0.2243023j , ...,  0.68834226+0.06496256j,
        -0.02286238+0.03550603j,  0.10621082+0.0017906j ],
       [ 0.04219961+0.03750657j, -0.41050630-0.03515527j,
        -0.10442910-0.03450125j, ..., -0.20640545-0.00679942j,
         0.55934004-0.03639518j,  0.07098921+0.02929779j],
       [ 0.09551901-0.03121943j, -0.20974550-0.11607423j,
        -0.19168294-0.01187921j, ..., -0.23618268+0.09158539j,
        -0.18803705+0.00693476j,  0.63079575+0.02476722j]])
```

In any case I can't tell you why there isn't such a function because I'm not a `scipy.sparse` developer.  But this brief exploration indicates that such a function isn't practical.  To show otherwise, you need to come up with example arrays - preferably ones where a sparse matrix has a sparse sqrtm, and where the calculation would be faster than if done with the dense equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. You are right, the `sqrtm` is in scipy's linalg and not numpy. I have edited my question to reflect that fact.
Also, my question was regarding matrices that for them the square root mathematically exists (i.e., are not singular).

Comment: OK, I found a larger sparse matrix that has a sqrtm - but one that is very dense.